# Customizing git commands in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to customize the git commands that are available in the ellipsis menu on the source control panel of VSCode?[image]

Comment: I mean customize like adding additional git commands or changing the existing commands for say "git pull" to something like "git pull -rebase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a custom extension for this, but yes, its possible.

As a reference point how to write one, there is a plugin I am using for creating git tags that integrates nicely in the menu. See https://github.com/leftstick/vscode-git-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Part of [`leftstick/vscode-git-tags`](https://github.com/leftstick/vscode-git-tags) just got more complete with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020) and [issue 109799](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109799):

> ### Git: Support `Git: Push Tags` command

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/da175982113f730d04e7a1001cb4e75be394b60551ee680b12d2375d38fa9a14/68747470733a2f2f63646e2e696d6770726f786966792e636f6d2f696d672f333430306664363131373137633633323537383834633130356439343166653836643133613432623435356333323034323962653562623535663230656534642e706e67]

Its [PR 110096](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/110096) represents a good example of menu customization.